# How to get link inside tag a html (html as plain text) in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have the following code

```
$input = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<a class="class1 class2" href="link-to-web1.html">Link</a>
<a class="class1 class2" href="abc/link-to-web1.html">Link</a>
<a class="class1 class2" href="abc/xyz/link-to-web1.html">Link</a>

<a class="another" href="abc/xyz/link.html">Link</a>
</body>
</html>';
```

I got this string after using curl. Then I wanna get all link (href link) of all a tag with class 'class1 class2', how to do that? I had tried some method but it's not work :(

Comment: can you please post the method you tried on here?

Comment: $dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($input);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$result = $xpath->query('//a[contains(@class, "class1 class2")]');
And then I got that result:
  >object(DOMNodeList)[51]
  >public 'length' => int 48

Comment: @VanTho post that as part of the question.

Comment: I got the answer from @Ravinder Reddy, and that code work perfect, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the DOMDocument

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
// load your html
$dom->loadHTML($input);
// loop all the anchor tags 
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a) {
     // check the calss
     if($a->getattribute('class') == 'class1 class2') {
          // echo href 
          echo $a->getattribute('href')."<br/>";
     }
}
```

Out put:

```
link-to-web1.html
abc/link-to-web1.html
abc/xyz/link-to-web1.html
```